# Haskell partial sum of a list error

Tags: haskell

I need to write a function in Haskell that sums the elements of a list until some specific elements stored in another list.

For example `partial_add [1,2,3,4,5,6] [2,5] 0` should return `[3,12,6]`.

I have reached this far:

```
partial_add [] _ count = []
partial_add (a:x) list count | elem a list =  count:partial_add x list 0
                             | otherwise =  partial_add x list count+a
```

(most probably not working properly)

But when I try to run the function (it compiles properly) I get this error:

```
No instance for (Num [t0]) arising from a use of `it' 
In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
```

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: Hint: the statement `partial_add x list count+a` is interpreted as `(partial_add x list count)+a` not `partial_add x list (count+a)`.

Comment: Hint2: Check `partial_add`'s type. Then try to add the correct type signature yourself.

Comment: Thank you everyone! I needed to declare the type partial_add :: [Int] -> [Int] -> Int -> [Int] and add the parenthesis around count+a

Comment: @PanosPaparrigopoulos: You can answer your own questions, so don't forget to add an answer later.

Comment: Note also that the `a` value gets lost if ``a `elem` list`` holds, so you may want to adjust that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your example, I would write the function something like this:

```
partialAdd :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int]
partialAdd ls seps = foldr f [] ls
  where 
    f a [] = [a]
    f a (x:xs)
      | a `elem` seps = a:x:xs
      | otherwise = (x+a):xs

*Main> partialAdd [1,2,3,4,5,6] [2,5]
[3,12,6]
```

Btw. I think the solution in your question seems not to work quite the way you specified in your example (or I misunderstood something):

```
partial_add :: [Int] -> [Int] -> Int -> [Int]
partial_add [] _ count = []
partial_add (a:x) list count | elem a list =  count:partial_add x list 0
                             | otherwise =  partial_add x list (count+a)

*Main> partial_add [1,2,3,4,5,6] [2,5] 0
[1,7]
```

But it is easily fixed to work for your example:

```
partial_add :: [Int] -> [Int] -> Int -> [Int]
partial_add [] _ count = [count]
partial_add (a:x) list count | elem a list =  (count+a):partial_add x list 0
                             | otherwise =  partial_add x list (count+a)

*Main> partial_add [1,2,3,4,5,6] [2,5] 0
[3,12,6]
```

Comment: Thank you @bmk it was indeed not working properly. The second code you posted is what i did to finaly.

Answer (score 1):

*Note: I am a bit confused by the `count` parameter since it is ignored in one of the recursive calls, where it is always passed as `0`. It should be easy to add its behavior once it's more clear what it does.*

Another way to look at this is to first separate the second list* into sublists *delimited by* (and including) the elements of the first list and then to find the sums of each sublist:

```
-- | A version of Data.List.splitOneOf that includes the delimiter
splitOneOf' :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> [[a]]
splitOneOf' _ [] = [[]]
splitOneOf' delims (x:xs) | x `elem` delims = [x] : splitOneOf' delims xs
splitOneOf' delims (x:xs) | otherwise = let (ys:yss) = splitOneOf' delims xs
                                        in (x:ys) : yss

partialAdd :: (Eq a, Num a) => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
partialAdd delims = map sum . splitOneOf' delims

main :: IO ()
main = print $ partialAdd [2,5] [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

gives

```
[3,12,6]
```

I think this is a nice example of "bottom up" programming in Haskell.

* I reversed the argument order to match the order used by `Data.List.Split`.

Comment: passing the count as 0 is my way to reset the counter :P don't know if there is a better way but it's only my third day working on haskell and i am a bit influeced by prolog. Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Thank to your answers i figured it out.
I needed to declare the type of the function and put the parenthesis where they should be.
The code was indeed not working as it should but i fixed that to.

Here is the fixed code:

```
partial_add :: [Int] -> [Int] -> Int -> [Int]        
partial_add [] _ count = [count]
partial_add (a:x) list count | elem a list =  (count+a):partial_add x list 0
                             | otherwise =  partial_add x list (count+a)
```

It may not be the best possible but it worked out for me.